# How to find latest row in a table corresponding to each row in a different table?

Tags: mysql

I thought I will get answer for this query straight away but I didn't find any Q&A which was exactly what I am looking for.

So, I have two tables.

Table 1: `id,c_id,created_at`

Table 2:`id,c_id,b_date,s_type`

I want a query which gives output corresponds to each row in table 1. ***The output should be the `latest b_date in table 2 prior to created_at` in Table 1 and the s_type corresponding to the latest b_date***. The linking condition between Table 1 and Table 2 is`c_id`. Both the tables have multiple rows containing same `c_id`.

My table 1,table 2 and output will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfzYV.png).
I am not allowed to embed images as of now. So please click to see the images.

Comment: Please don't force people to burn 10 minutes creating your schema and data load when you could just do it for them

Comment: See my ridiculous but still serious [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38899464)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this

```
SELECT T1.ID,T1.C_ID,T1.CREATED_AT,T2.B_DATE,T2.S_TYPE
FROM    TABLE1 T1
JOIN  TABLE2 T2 ON T1.C_ID = T2.C_ID
WHERE   T2.B_DATE = (SELECT MAX(T3.B_DATE) FROM TABLE2 T3 WHERE T3.b_DATE < T1.CREATED_AT AND T3.C_ID = T1.C_ID)
;
```

or maybe this

```
SELECT S.ID,S.C_ID,S.CREATED_AT,S.B_DATE,T.S_TYPE
FROM
(
SELECT T1.ID,T1.C_ID,T1.CREATED_AT,T2.B_DATE,T2.S_TYPE
FROM    TABLE1 T1
JOIN  TABLE2 T2 ON T1.C_ID = T2.C_ID
WHERE   T2.B_DATE = (SELECT MAX(T3.B_DATE) FROM TABLE2 T3 WHERE T3.b_DATE < T1.CREATED_AT AND T3.C_ID = T1.C_ID)
) S
JOIN 
(SELECT T1.ID,T1.C_ID,T1.CREATED_AT,T2.B_DATE,T2.S_TYPE
FROM    TABLE1 T1
JOIN  TABLE2 T2 ON T1.C_ID = T2.C_ID
WHERE   T2.B_DATE = (SELECT MAX(T3.B_DATE) FROM TABLE2 T3 WHERE T3.C_ID = T1.C_ID)
) T ON S.C_ID = T.C_ID
;
```